# if else in sql function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table something similar to this:(THE FIRST ROW ARE HEADERS)

ID      --peach    --cherry  --plum --berry  --apple     --mango       --orange --grapes

932     --peach    --NULL    --NULL--NULL    --NULL     --NULL    --NULL        --NULL

932    --NULL      --NULL    --NULL   --berry--NULL     --mango  --NULL      --NULL

932    --NULL      --NULL    -- NULL--berry  --NULL     --mango  --NULL --NULL

926    --NULL      --cherry  --NULL--NULL    --apple    --NULL   --NULL --NULL

926    --NULL      --cherry  --NULL--NULL    --apple    --NULL   --NULL --grapes

I am trying to create a function that would get the ID and pick the initial from every other column if present and then concatenate them like below

ID     fruits

932    P

932    B,M

932    B,M

932    C,A

932    C,A,G

whats the best to do this and create a function which i can call later to create a final table. Any help is appreciated. The table has about 51,000 rows.

Comment: How many columns are there? Do you want to hardcode the columns or pull them dynamically?

Comment: The first table has 99 columns including the ID, AND the result table should have on two with ID and the other that has concatenated value of the first initials of every fruit present. I am passing the parameters through a function to check if the column values are present

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

SAMPLE DATA:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp1(ID     INT
           , peach  VARCHAR(10)
           , cherry VARCHAR(10)
           , plum   VARCHAR(10)
           , berry  VARCHAR(10)
           , apple  VARCHAR(10)
           , mango  VARCHAR(10)
           , orange VARCHAR(10)
           , grapes VARCHAR(10));


INSERT INTO #temp1
VALUES
(932,'peach' , NULL ,  NULL ,  NULL ,   NULL ,  NULL ,  NULL,  NULL  ),
(932,NULL  , NULL   ,NULL   ,'berry'  , NULL   ,'mango'  ,NULL  ,NULL  ),
(932,NULL  , NULL   ,NULL   ,'berry'  , NULL   ,'mango'  ,NULL  ,NULL  ),
(926,NULL  , 'cherry' ,NULL   ,NULL   , 'apple'  ,NULL   ,NULL  ,NULL  ),
(926,NULL  , 'cherry' ,NULL   ,NULL   , 'apple'  ,NULL   ,NULL  ,'grapes')
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT #temp1.ID
    , ISNULL(SUBSTRING(#temp1.peach,1,1),'')
    + ISNULL(SUBSTRING(#temp1.cherry,1,1),'')
    + ISNULL(SUBSTRING(#temp1.plum,1,1),'')
    + ISNULL(SUBSTRING(#temp1.berry,1,1),'')
    + ISNULL(SUBSTRING(#temp1.apple,1,1),'')
    + ISNULL(SUBSTRING(#temp1.mango,1,1),'')
    + ISNULL(SUBSTRING(#temp1.orange,1,1),'')
    + ISNULL(SUBSTRING(#temp1.grapes,1,1),'')
FROM   #temp1;
```

RESULT:

[image]

Comment: Hey @Kamran Farzami Thanks, but I need to write a function to do this, do you think this would work when the column values are passed as parameters in a UDF

Comment: So I came up with this to format the output with commas and delete the commas when a a value is null
SELECT q.account_id,REPLACE(RTRIM(REPLACE(q.prod, ',', ' ')), ' ', ',')
    from 
 (select account_id,
 (
 COALESCE (NULLIF(ISNULL(SUBSTRING(example.apple,1,4) + space(1)),''),'') + ',','')
  + COALESCE (NULLIF(ISNULL(SUBSTRING(example.mango,1,1) + space(1)),''),'') + ',','')
  + COALESCE (NULLIF(ISNULL(SUBSTRING(example.orange,1,1) + space(1)),''),'') + ',','')
  + COALESCE  (NULLIF(ISNULL(SUBSTRING(example.peach,1,1) + space(1)),''),'') ,'')
  ) as prod 
 FROM   example
  )as q

Comment: @my_way that looks good. When I put the answer up I forgot to add the commas.

Comment: It works fine without the space function but I need to get the output with a trailing space after every sub-string value, like 'A  ', 'P  '

What would be the best way to get the spaces after getting the sub string?

Comment: @my_way do you want the spaces or not?

Comment: I want the spaces but the space function that I am using in my code doesnt work.

Comment: you can always do REPLACE(<the code here>,',',' ,')

Comment: SELECT q.account_id,REPLACE(q.prod,',',' ,')   --REPLACE(RTRIM(REPLACE(q.prod, ',', ' ')), ' ', ',')
    from 
 (select account_id,
  (
 COALESCE (NULLIF(ISNULL(SUBSTRING(example.COAG,1,4),''),'') + ',','')
  + COALESCE (NULLIF(ISNULL(SUBSTRING(example.DIM,1,1),''),'') + ',','')
  + COALESCE (NULLIF(ISNULL(SUBSTRING(example.IMM,1,1),''),'') + ',','')
  + COALESCE  (NULLIF(ISNULL(SUBSTRING(example.VISTA,1,1),''),'') ,'')
  ) as prod 
 FROM   example
  )as q

Comment: So I added the replace right at the start in the select statement but now I get a trailing comma after the space where ever there is only one fruit present or only the first and second. A example would be:

1-- a ,m ,o, p
2--a ,
3--a ,m ,